# Using a button to scroll a uicollectionview - how do i check bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I don't know how to figure out whether I get to the last `IndexPath` and when to "rewind" and scroll to the first `IndexPath`
This is some setup:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
{
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (id)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 768.0f);
} else {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 768.0f);
}

[flowLayout invalidateLayout]; //force the elements to get laid out again with the new size

visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
self.currentIndexPath = [visibleItems firstObject];
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

This is my button code:

```
- (IBAction)addToUploadQueque:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"current: %@",self.currentIndexPath);

NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger item = [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section]-1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
NSIndexPath *firstIndexpath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

NSLog(@"current: %@",lastIndexPath);
if (self.currentIndexPath <= lastIndexPath) {
    NSInteger newLast = [self.currentIndexPath indexAtPosition:self.currentIndexPath.length-1]+1;
    self.currentIndexPath = [[self.currentIndexPath indexPathByRemovingLastIndex] indexPathByAddingIndex:newLast];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.currentIndexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
}else{
    self.currentIndexPath = [visibleItems firstObject];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.currentIndexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
}

}
```

I'm making a button that iterates through each cell in the collection view and when it gets to the end (instead of going out of bounds) scroll back to the first cell.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your comments, it doesn't sound like you want to just enumerate the visible cells in one pass, but rather want to enumerate through them manually. And it sounds like you're having an issue getting the next `NSIndexPath`. The problem with your code snippet is that you're incrementing the `row`/`item` (depending upon whether you're dealing with `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`), but not considering whether you've reached the end of a section, much less the end of the data source, before you try to use your incremented data source.

You could do something like:

```
NSInteger item = self.currentIndexPath.item;
NSInteger section = self.currentIndexPath.section;

item++;                                                                    // go to next item
if (item >= [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section]) {        // if you reached end of section ...
    item = 0;                                                              // ... go to the start of the next section
    section++;
    if (section >= [self.collectionView numberOfSections]) {               // if you reached the end of the data source ...
        // all done, so set section to zero to go back to beginning, e.g.  // ... then you're done
        section = 0;
    }
}
self.currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section]; // otherwise, this is your new NSIndexPath
```

BTW, if we're going to focus on your code snippet, the another issue is that you're using the `<=` operator to compare two index paths. You cannot do that. You have to use the `compare` method of `NSIndexPath`.

But that `if` statement strikes me as unnecessary, as there is no index path in the data source after the last index path. If you're incrementing logic (above) correctly detects the end of the data source, then this `if` statement is unnecessary.

---

There are many, many issues in this code. But I'm wondering whether, rather than going through all of those details, whether a simpler approach is possible. If you just want to perform uploads for all of the visible rows, perhaps you could do something radically simpler, such as:

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems) {
    // if the cell has some visual indication to reflect upload has been initiated,
    // do that here

    // do your asynchronous upload here, where the completion block dispatches 
    // updates to the cell/collectionView (to reflect that the individual upload
    // is done)
}
```

Note, your code is scrolling to the cell (presumably when the upload is done). I might try to dissuade you from that approach, but instead just update the cell (e.g. set some flag that your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method references, and then call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` for each row as that row finishes. Because uploads can be slow, you might not want the UI scrolling around as these asynchronous uploads finish.

Comment: That sounds much simpler for the upload, but I'm going to use a table view to display that. what I'm trying to do is use a button to cycle through all the cells and "tag" them for upload (in the upload view that has the tableview) then using NSnotificationcenter to update both views. So most of the upload work is done in a different view (popover). in the collection view - its presented fullscreen in landscape (iPad) with a yes and no button. the yes button I want to advance the view and tag it for upload, but I'm getting an out of bounds error when i hit the last cell.

Comment: @rcpilotp51 Yeah, you're going to get an out of bounds at the end of every section (including the end of the table view) because you're just incrementing the `item` of the `indexPath`, but not checking to see if that exceeds the number of items in that section. We could remedy that portion of your code sample, but I'd personally just enumerate through the visible cells and flag them to be uploaded. Your code sample was for collection view, so I used collection view, too, but the idea is the same for tableview, except you'd use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` rather than `indexPathsForVisibleItems`.

Comment: i need to enumerate through the collection view using a button and I need to check the bounds so i don't get the out of bounds error (thats what i don't know)

Comment: @rcpilotp51 OK, given your reluctance to iterate through them in one fell swoop, I'm gathering that you want to do this manually, and only want to get the `NSIndexPath` for the next cell, in which case you could use the code in my revised answer.

Comment: I don't think you understand. I don't need to work with tableviews. Im trying to navigate a`uicollectionview` using a "next button" instead of swiping. Using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` I'm able to cycle through, but i can't tell when I'm at the end of the assets in the collection view. say there are 4 items in the collection view. when i get to the 4th item, and hit next I would like to scroll back to the first one. the collection view displays a cell in full landscape (iPad), one at a time. (forget about the uploads and all that in the last question) just interested in the bounds.

Comment: i can probably adapt your tableview code above to a collection using item instead of row.....

Comment: @rcpilotp51 Yes. I only used tableview because even though the original question was about collection views, your first comment above made some reference to table views. But the idea is exactly the same for collection views: Check to see if, after incrementing the `item` number, if you've exceeded the number of items in that section, and if so, progress to the next section, and then make sure you haven't exceeded the number of sections in that collection view. See revised code sample.